# How to deal with non-normal variable distributions in R glmnet

Tags: r, data-transformation, heteroscedasticity

I am regressing actual counts of traffic against predictions using ridge regression (`cv.glmnet` in R).  The data (both predicted and actual) has a roughly exponential distribution, i.e. a few large values (which are important to predict) and many small ones.  Residuals in the model are usually proportional to the size of the target variable.

What is the best approach to fit such a model correctly?

Transform both predicted and target data beforehand (cube root, log, Box-Cox)?

Or is there something I can do with the estimating process that negates the need to do this - by treating errors in large values as less bad than errors in small ones?

Comment: Doesn't `cv.glmnet` support Poisson regression directly?  Although in my experience it can fail to converge on moderate to large problems, of all the options available it would be the first method to try with count data.

Comment: I was under the impression a Poisson regression (i.e. log link function) would be wrong if the relationship between my Xs and Y is linear?  While both are distributed exponentially I still expect a linear relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a great deal of the point of using `glmnet`. The residuals don't have to be normal (note that it was always the residuals that need normality in ordinary regression and not the data). Your data are counts and will typically follow a distribution that looks exponential that's called a Poisson distribution. You can set the kind of distribution with the `family` argument in `glmnet`. See the help on `glmnet` as well as `cv.glmnet`. The `...` argument that is available in `cv.glmnet` means you can pass the same arguments that you do to `glmnet` where required, as in this case.

Once you've passed the correct arguments the software will handle the generation of the model correctly. However, make certain that you additionally read up on understanding regression coefficients for Poisson regression.

Comment: "... an exponential distribution that's called a Poisson distribution" is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: Is a poisson regression still right if the relationship between my Xs and Y is linear?

Comment: @whuber Ooops, that wasn't my intent... hopefully it's fixed.

Comment: Sideshow, you can look at fit of the distribution for your case because I don't know what scale you're looking at linearity (you talked about exponential looking properties of both variables). The most critical thing is that using a Poisson model is dealing with the variance that inflates with count.

Comment: John, thanks, I get that variance inflates with count, as you put it.  But I thought Poisson handled this by introducing a log linking function which implies $log(y)=\beta X+\epsilon$ rather than $y=\beta x + \epsilon$ the latter being what I need?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is there but it sounds like a new question and not something for a comment.

Comment: Hi John, sorry for not making this clearer.  I think this is the same question, because if Poisson implies a nonlinear relationship between X and Y then it's not a suitable approach where the data have a linear relationship.  Both my predictor and target variable are exponentially distributed, but the relationship between them is still linear.  So my question is, can I use Poisson where the relationship between X and Y is linear?

Comment: The distribution and fit aren't necessarily related, that's why I said it should be a new question. You can have all kinds of distribution shapes with linear relationships. Your question is about distribution at first and now you're talking about fit and are conflating the terms. Thats making it difficult to answer. Consider that locally all models are linear. Just run the models and see what fits better. Your bigger problem is dealing with that inflating error term and matching the nature of the data. You might want to ask a question that includes your data.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm afraid I'm struggling to formulate the new question which is why these comments are helpful!  will try now...

Comment: One further question on your answer above.  "The residuals don't have to be normal": is this true no matter what regression family is used within glmnet?

Comment: No, if the assumption is a normal distribution of residuals, such as if you were using a normal gaussian, then they should be.